# Power BI: Calculations not working properly

Tags: powerbi

I have a table containing Resource Name, Resources Owner, Project Name, Project Manager, Effort.
For Every resource owner, I want to calculate the loaned out efforts(efforts spent by resources of owner in projects other than owner's project) and borrowed efforts (efforts spent by resources of owner in other's project except the project owner's).

```
For e.g., Resource Owner = X
Project Manager = AllExcept(X)
Sum(Effort) = Loaned Out Hours

Resource Owner = AllExcept(X)
Project Manager = X
Sum(Effort) = Borrowed.
```

For calculating loaned out hours I am using this DAX Formula-

```
Loaned = IF(ISBLANK(CALCULATE(SUM('All_Activity Data'[Logged Effort]), FILTER('All_Activity Data','All_Activity Data'[Project Manager] <> 'All_Activity Data'[Resource Owner]))),0,CALCULATE(SUM('All_Activity Data'[Logged Effort]),FILTER('All_Activity Data','All_Activity Data'[Project Manager] <> 'All_Activity Data'[Resource Owner])))
```

For calculating borrowed I am using -

```
Borrowed = IF(ISBLANK(CALCULATE(SUM('All_Activity Data'[Logged Effort]),FILTER('All_Activity Data','All_Activity Data'[Project Manager] <> 'All_Activity Data'[Resource Owner]), FILTER('All_Activity Data','All_Activity Data'[Project Manager] = 'All_Activity Data'[Resource Owner]))),0,CALCULATE(SUM('All_Activity Data'[Logged Effort]),FILTER('All_Activity Data','All_Activity Data'[Project Manager] <> 'All_Activity Data'[Resource Owner]), FILTER('All_Activity Data','All_Activity Data'[Project Manager] = 'All_Activity Data'[Resource Owner])))
```

Loaned hours are calculating properly but not borrowed out. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is sample data:

```
RN      Eff     PN  P_M RO
NAME 1  1.50    A   O   X
NAME 2  8.00    B   N   S
NAME 1  5.50    C   N   S
NAME 2  1.50    D   S   S
NAME 1  5.00    E   X   S
NAME 2  8.00    F   N   N
NAME 1  4.00    G   L   X
NAME 2  4.00    H   L   X
NAME 1  0.25    I   X   N
NAME 2  0.25    G   O   X
NAME 1  0.25    A   X   D
NAME 2  6.75    B   N   X
NAME 1  0.50    C   X   X
NAME 2  8.00    D   N   L
NAME 1  0.17    E   D   D
NAME 2  2.26    F   D   D
NAME 1  1.58    G   L   D
NAME 2  2.50    H   D   D
NAME 2  0.58    I   D   D
NAME 1  0.33    G   D   D
NAME 2  0.34    A   D   D
NAME 1  0.25    B   D   D
NAME 2  6.00    C   D   S
NAME 1  0.30    D   N   S
NAME 1  8.00    E   N   N
NAME 2  2.00    F   S   S
NAME 1  4.50    G   S   S
NAME 2  1.50    H   S   S
NAME 1  2.00    I   S   S
NAME 2  1.50    G   S   S
NAME 2  4.50    A   S   S
NAME 2  8.00    B   S   S
NAME 2  8.00    C   S   L
NAME 2  8.00    D   N   S
NAME 2  8.00    E   S   L
NAME 2  8.00    F   S   L
NAME 2  8.00    G   O   X
NAME 2  1.25    H   L   L
NAME 2  2.75    I   L   L
NAME 1  0.75    G   L   L
NAME 1  1.50    A   L   L
NAME 1  0.75    B   O   L
NAME 1  1.25    C   O   X
NAME 1  0.50    D   N   X
NAME 1  1.00    E   X   X
NAME 1  2.00    F   O   X
NAME 1  2.50    G   S   N
NAME 1  7.00    H   S   N
NAME 1  1.50    I   L   N
NAME 2  6.50    G   L   N
NAME 2  8.00    A   N   S
NAME 2  8.00    B   N   X
NAME 2  7.50    C   L   S
NAME 1  3.25    D   N   N
NAME 1  2.25    E   N   N
NAME 1  0.75    F   N   N
NAME 2  0.75    G   N   N
NAME 1  1.00    H   L   X
NAME 1  4.00    I   S   X
NAME 1  3.00    G   N   X
NAME 2  8.00    A   L   L
NAME 1  6.00    B   N   N
NAME 1  0.50    C   N   N
NAME 1  0.50    D   N   N
NAME 2  7.00    E   N   X
NAME 1  0.25    F   O   X
NAME 1  0.50    G   O   X
NAME 1  0.25    H   X   X
```

In this case-
Loaned out For X PM is - 52
Borrowed in is - 5.5
 [image: Loaned out]

[image: Borrowedin]

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly is the problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Data coming after calculation is not matching with original excel sheets. Formula for calculate measures is not working.

Comment: Can you add an example? Would be useful to see sample data, your result and expected result.

Comment: @user5226582 here is the sample data

Comment: @teylyn any idea how to solve this problem in PBI.

Comment: I think your question is confusing because you say "Borrowed hours and loaned hours are calculating properly" - presumably you mean "are *not* calculating properly"? You also provide the numbers you're expecting, but never say what numbers you're actually getting.

Comment: @Leonard I will some post the result I am getting after calculation. Thanks for pointing out mistake in my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 types of effort in your question:

The easiest type of effort is "not loaned or borrowed effort" - where the manager you care about is both the resource owner and the project manager (i.e. they are using resources they manage on a project they manage).

The next type of effort is "loaned effort" - where the manager you care about is the resource owner but not the project manager (i.e. the manager's resources are being used on someone else's project).

The final type of effort is "borrowed effort" - where the manager you care about is the project manager but not the resource owner (i.e. they are using someone else's resources on their project).

You have loaned effort defined correctly, but it's based on the assumption that the resource owner is the manager you care about. Indeed, your *Loaned Effort* calculation is perfectly correct for *Borrowed Effort* too, except you would need to display the table by Project Manager instead of Resource Owner (this is because Project Managers borrow and Resource Owners lend - but otherwise it's the same calculation).

[image: Loaned is Borrowed]

**The essence of your problem is, therefore, not to a problem with the calculation, but rather because you want to display the "borrowed" and "loaned" number side-by-side for the same person.**

To accomplish this, I recommend having a separate, de-duped table of managers that you can calculate the borrowed and loaned number for. One of the main reasons for doing this is because a manager may borrow but never lend. If you start with the premise of resource owners (who lend), the manager who borrows but never lends will never appear in your results.

I called this table DimManager, with a single column *Manager*. You can obviously vary this. I did **not** relate this table to All_Activity Data:

[image: DimManager Table]

Then, for the measures, I started with not loaned or borrowed, where I want the manager to be both the project manager and the resource owner:

```
Not Loaned or Borrowed =
SUMX (
    'DimManager',
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX (
            FILTER (
                'All_Activity Data',
                'All_Activity Data'[Project Manager] = MAX ( 'DimManager'[Manager] )
                    && 'All_Activity Data'[Resource Owner] = MAX ( 'DimManager'[Manager] )
            ),
            'All_Activity Data'[Logged Effort]
        )
    )
)
```

Working from the inside out, the FILTER is what is doing the join between the two unrelated tables. In this case saying that I want the Manager to be both the Project Manager and the Resource Owner. The nested SUMX(CALCULATE(SUMX is so that, when calculating a column total, it sums the result of each individual manager. Without this, the measure would use the MAX(Manager) for the column totals, making the column totals the same as Manager X in your sample data. I learnt about this trick from Matt Allington: https://exceleratorbi.com.au/double-calculate-solves-sumx-problem/

For your loaned and borrowed calculations, they are exactly the same as above, except instead of saying you want both your Resource Owner and Project Manager to match your manager, one of them does not match your manager:

```
Loaned =
SUMX (
    'DimManager',
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX (
            FILTER (
                'All_Activity Data',
                'All_Activity Data'[Project Manager] <> MAX ( 'DimManager'[Manager] )
                    && 'All_Activity Data'[Resource Owner] = MAX ( 'DimManager'[Manager] )
            ),
            'All_Activity Data'[Logged Effort]
        )
    )
)
```

'

```
Borrowed =
SUMX (
    'DimManager',
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX (
            FILTER (
                'All_Activity Data',
                'All_Activity Data'[Project Manager] = MAX ( 'DimManager'[Manager] )
                    && 'All_Activity Data'[Resource Owner] <> MAX ( 'DimManager'[Manager] )
            ),
            'All_Activity Data'[Logged Effort]
        )
    )
)
```

This results in the final result below:

[image: Final Result]

Comment: Can I not use Manager names in my All_Activity Data table? When I use All_Activity Data table's Resource Owner as Manager,  Borrow becomes blank.

Comment: Your *Borrowed* equation as it stands in the question has a contradiction. You are summing effort where the project manager does not equal the resource manager **AND** where the project manager equals the resource manager. Since it's not possible for any row to both equal and not equal, the result will always be zero.

Comment: In theory, there is a way to get a *Borrowed* equation to work based on Resource Owner. The calculation would be the *Loaned* equation but you'd need to override the context filter on the current resource owner and instead calculate the loaned amount for other resource owners lending to the current resource owner. However, as I say in my answer, doing this will drop any borrowing done by project managers that are not resource owners

Comment: The way I'd approach it would require having a single current resource owner (to represent who is doing the borrowing). E.g. *Borrowed = CALCULATE([Loaned], FILTER(ALL('All_Activity Data'), [Resource Owner] <> MAX([Resource Owner]) && MAX([Resource Owner]) = [Project Manager]))*     However, sub-totals and roll-ups involve more than one resource owner, so wouldn't work. Drill-downs that involve splitting a single resource owner up between multiple rows also wouldn't work. Slicers/filters on other columns would be ignored. The calculation is very brittle compared to the solution in my answer.

Comment: Other people with more experience might have a better solution for what you want though. I certainly don't claim to be the last word on this.