# power bi: split column values by character and calculate sum

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table in which numeric values are there, but in some rows may contains values separated by comma. Since comma is in there so the data type of the column will be text.
I want to calculate sum of this column.

Here is my table-

```
Id  Values
A   12
B   13
C   15
D   13,11,12
E   16
```

I want my sum to be - `12+13+15+13+11+12+16`

Since the datatype of this column will be text so can the sum be calculated like I want or I have to do something like this-

```
      Id  Values
        A   12
        B   13
        C   15
        D   13
        D   11
        D   12
        E   16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the column by delimiter:

[image: split]

And split it into rows instead of columns:

[image: option]

The result will be as what you expected:

[image: result]

Then you can sum it as usual with DAX:

```
Sum = SUM(Data[Values])
```

[image: sum]

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: Can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884315/power-bi-calculations-not-working-properly

Comment: @Sonali You can mark it as the correct answer to positively close the question.